# Getting headers from html (parsing)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

The source is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States. I am looking to use the table called "COVID-19 pandemic in the United States by state and territory" which is the third diagram on the page.
Here is my code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
with open("COVID-19 pandemic in the United States - Wikipedia.htm", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(fd)
    print(soup.prettify())
```

```
all_tables = soup.find_all("table")
print("The total number of tables are {} ".format(len(all_tables)))
```

```
data_table = soup.find("div", {"class": 'mw-stack stack-container stack-clear-right mobile-float-reset'})
print(type(data_table))
```

```
sources = data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[0]

sources_list = [td for td in sources.findAll('td')]

print(len(sources_list))
```

```
data = data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1].findAll('td', recursive=False)
```

```
data_tables = []

for td in data:

    data_tables.append(td.findAll('table'))
```

```
header1 = [th.getText().strip() for th in data_tables[0][0].findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')]

header1
```

This last line with header1 i giving me the error "list index out of range". What it is supposed to print is "U.S State or territory....."

I don't know anything about html, and everything gets me stuck and confused. The soup.find could also be referencing the wrong part of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

by looking at your code, I think you should call the html tag by `find`, not by `find_all` in the title tag

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use

```py
headers = [element.text.strip() for element in data_table.find_all("th")]
```

To get the text in the headers?

To get the entire table as a pandas dataframe, you can do:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
data_table = soup.find("div", {"class": 'mw-stack stack-container stack-clear-right mobile-float-reset'})
rows = data_table.find_all("tr")

# Delete first row as it's not part of the table and confuses pandas
# this removes it from both soup and data_table
rows[0].decompose()
# Same for third row
rows[2].decompose()
# Same for last two rows
rows[-1].decompose()
rows[-2].decompose()

# Read html with pandas
df = pd.read_html(str(data_table))[0]

# Keep only the useful columns
df = df[['U.S. state or territory[i].1', 'Cases[ii]', 'Deaths', 'Recov.[iii]', 'Hosp.[iv]']]

# Rename columns
df.columns = ["State", "Cases", "Deaths", "Recov.", "Hosp."]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier in these cases to try to read tables with pandas, and go from there:

```
import pandas as pd

table = soup.select_one("div#covid19-container table")
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df
```

The output is the target table.